# AWS EKS and VPC cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, boto3, amazon-vpc, subnet, amazon-eks

I'm creating EKS cluster and VPC via cloudformation. My VPC have four subnets and from that, I am giving two subnets to EKS cluster. But after giving two subnets It is giving error **Subnets specified must be in at least two different AZs (Service: AmazonEKS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException** where I already have given two subnets. When I give three subnets it creates EKS successfully.

I EKS cluster is of 3 node. I tried to create of 2 node also but it not worked.

My VPC info.

Subnet01Block   192.168.0.0/24

Subnet02Block   192.168.64.0/24

Subnet03Block   192.168.128.0/24

Subnet04Block   192.168.192.0/24

VpcBlock    192.168.0.0/16

Comment: The subnets you were selecting were not in the same AZ it seems. See the AZ's of the subnets and choose 2 different ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html), you must select different subnets which belong to different AZs. So you need to update your VPC configuration.

```
When you create an Amazon EKS cluster, you specify the Amazon VPC subnets for your cluster to use. Amazon EKS requires subnets in at least two Availability Zones
```

Answer (score 1):

When you select subnets for EKS, in the options, next to the subnets you see letters- a,b,c etc. Choose unique letters of the same subnet and you should be good to go.